# Names/Text missing in my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gui

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 and now I have this issue.[image: Screenshot]
The file names and some texts are missing. I had this issue earlier but it didn't exist after rebooting the system. I don't want this problem again, do tell me what I can do :)

Comment: Happens to me sometimes when logged in with two users and switching between them from TTY-7 to TTY-8 and back. I cannot reproduce it, just happens occasionally. After a reboot everything is good again. Is quite annoying.